# Running a script with a command

Tags: 11.10, command-line

How do I make a new command to run a script, for example if I type `runme` (from any dir) it will run `/run/me/script.sh`?
Seems simple but I can find anywhere that explains how to do this :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply add /run/me to your PATH, any script put there could be simply run from any directory

how to PATH from troubleshooters.com 
To add directory /data/myscripts to the beginning of the $PATH environment variable, use the following:

```
PATH=/data/myscripts:$PATH
```

To add that directory to the end of the path, use the following command:

```
PATH=$PATH:/data/myscripts
```

finally

```
export PATH
```

to have it everywhere, all the times, for your user only, add these in place the lines in that user's **.bash_profile** file 
all users except root: add to /etc/profile 
for root: only possible by **root's** .bash_profile

my idea for the sake of laziness (not your case of running 'every' script though): add a symbolic link from a single script there to your /home/usr/loca/bin

Answer (score 1):

Two possiblities:

1. alias runme='/run/me/script.sh'
   at the bash command prompt. This works for this session only. Put this line in ~/.bashrc if you want this change to be persistent.
2. rename script.sh to runme and add /run/me to the PATH

http://nixcraft.com/shell-scripting/4490-how-can-i-set-path-bash-shell.html#post7234

P.S.: Make sure script.sh has executable rights (chmod +x script.sh)

Comment: Huh? I need it run from any directory.. My friend has stuff installed on the server in `/usr/local/svn/usr/local/bin/` which I run scripts from by typing `a_script_in_that_dir` , but that is not my home dir, I tried putting a script into there to see if it would work but it didn't :/

Comment: If you type `echo $PATH` from the command line you will see all the directories (such as `/usr/local/`) that the shell looks for programs in. That is one method (#2 above). The other method addresses naming a script one thing, but calling it from the command line as another (aliasing)